# Submit form using webservice

Tags: php

I am building a form on my website. I want to save the details into some other database/website using some exposed web service from the other website. How can i do this. I have no idea about this. Can you give some steps on how to do it.

Comment: Any chance you can give us a little more information about this? We can see you want to use PHP but do you have any more information about the web service? Are you creating the web service as well or is it a pre-existing web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to build the "client" end (server with the form), "server" end (webservice receiving details) or both?

Client can use php_curl or similar to send data to a [REST webservice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) on the server

So something like this

User (fills out form) -> Frontend-server (PHP) -- [sends request with information] --> Backend-server (saved)

1. So a user would theoretically send to the frontend server `data data data`
2. The frontend server (PHP) uses curl to send the info to the backend server `http://backend.server.com/heres-some-info.php?data=data%20data%20data`
3. The backend server will save/process the data as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the website is with some hosting service (like godaddy.com), it will have support for MySQL database and a server side language - like PHP/Python, etc.

1. Make a form using the server side language which inserts values into the database.
2. Send data to the form from the app.